# Python regex delimiting a string

Tags: python, regex, string

[Answered first part, please scroll for second question edit]

Currently coding a web scraper in python.
I have the following example string:

`Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014`

I want to split it so that I have [Columbus Blue Jackets, Buffalo Sabres, 10/09/2014]

I read up on regular expressions including a few answers on this site but can't figure out how to format my particular example. The best I could come up with was something like this, although it doesn't work.

`re.split('\w+\s\w\w\s\w+\s\.\s\w+', teams)`

My second try is:
`re.split("\w+\s'at'\s\w+\s'-'\s\w+", teams)`, but I'm not sure if you can even enter exact strings like ['at' and '-'] inside a regex function.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong with the regex function or if there's another way to delimit my particular example in python.

(Also note that the team names can be either 2 or 3 words for each team, eg. `Montreal Canadiens at Buffalo Sabres`)

***EDIT:***
`re.split(r"\s+at\s+|\s+-\s+", teams)` seems to do the trick. However I now have a second problem. Testing it in its own file, this works, but in my program for some reason it doesn`t.

Code:

```
def getTable(url):
    currentMatchup = Crawl.setup(url)
    teams = currentMatchup.title.string
    print(teams)
    re.split(r"\s+at\s+|\s+-\s+", teams)
    print(teams)
```

The output is:

```
Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014
Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the input string according to `<space>at<space>` or `<space>-<space>`,

```
>>> s = "Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?:at|-)\s+', s)
['Columbus Blue Jackets', 'Buffalo Sabres', '10/09/2014']
>>> s = 'Montreal Canadiens at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014'
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?:at|-)\s+', s)
['Montreal Canadiens', 'Buffalo Sabres', '10/09/2014']
```

Through `re.findall` function,

```
>>> s = "Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014"
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\S+(?:\s+[A-Z]\S+){1,}|(?<=-\s)\S+', s)
['Columbus Blue Jackets', 'Buffalo Sabres', '10/09/2014']
```

Comment: chosen as answer due to efficiency

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.split(r"\s+at\s+|\s+-\s+",teams)
```

Output:`['Columbus Blue Jackets', 'Buffalo Sabres', '10/09/2014']`

Try this.You can do it in one line.Here `teams` is your string.This will give you desired results.

Edit:

```
def getTable(url):
    currentMatchup = Crawl.setup(url)
    teams = currentMatchup.title.string
    print(teams)
    y=re.split(r"\s+at\s+|\s+-\s+", teams)
    print(y)
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj's expression is the same, but more efficient (since the alternation occurs in a group and the `\s+` doesn't need to be re-matched).

Comment: this works in its own file but for some reason not in my program. I edited the question and added my code

Comment: Thanks @Sam, I'll check his out

Comment: @Tiberiu `x=re.split(r"\s+at\s+|\s+-\s+", teams)
    print(x)`

Comment: @Tiberiu `re.split` returns a list which you have to save.it does not make in place diting of string.save the list nad print it

Answer (score 0):

Capture them into groups with lazy dot-match-all repetition.

```
(.*?)\s+at\s+(.*?)\s+-\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/lU3wV3/1)

---

```
import re;

match = re.search(r"(.*?)\s+at\s+(.*?)\s+-\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})", "Columbus Blue Jackets at Buffalo Sabres - 10/09/2014")
print match.groups()

# ('Columbus Blue Jackets', 'Buffalo Sabres', '10/09/2014')
```

Comment: Just as a note to OP, there is nothing wrong with the answers using `.split()`; however, I believe my answer fits the scope of the question better. You are trying to extract 3 pieces of information from a string (team 1, team 2, and date). My expression does exactly that, unlike the others which just split a string into 3 pieces (essentially the same, yes).